# Failing to retrieve values from $.getJSON

Tags: jquery, getjson

I am trying to use $.getJSON to pull data from a server, but the results keep showing as undefined and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
var url="http://api.<domain>.com/<access token>/";
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {

    // values
    var ledState = data.ledState;
    console.log("ledState="+ledState);
});
```

This results in: "ledState=undefined" in the console.  If I stringify "data", I get:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1098",
        "readingTime": "2016-06-16 18:06:11",
        "bedLamp1": "0",
        "bedLamp2": "0",
        "bedOverhead": "0",
        "bedCandle": "0",
        "bedTemp": "76.47",
        "ledState": "1",
        "fadeSpeed": "5",
        "ledBrightness": "100",
        "autoSwamp": "1",
        "goalTemp": "77",
        "colorHEX": "00ffff",
        "outsideTemp": "113",
        "watts": "39.23",
        "lvTemp": "78",
        "lvHumidity": "20",
        "lvLamp": "0",
        "lvCandle": "0",
        "lvLedState": "0",
        "lvFadeSpeed": "10",
        "lvLedBrightness": "100",
        "lvColorHEX": "ff0033"
    }
]
```

What am I forgetting?

Comment: assuming you  can have more values for the data check this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4w2qn51y/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an Array of Objects so changing to

```
 var ledState = data[0].ledState;
```

should work

Comment: Ugh, I'm one second too late.